# Send javascript data to mysql server table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Im working on a quizz with php mysql and javascript, I haven't worked with javascript before so here is the thing, the function showScores shows to the user when the quizz has ended and the result of the answers.
But need to store the quiz.score into a mysql table, i don't know if that is possible due to php and javascript work in different side scriptig languages.

```
function showScores() {
    var gameOverHTML = "<br><h1>Quizz Finished</h1>";
    gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> Result: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
    var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
    element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML; 
};
```

Comment: You just need to do a little research on AJAX, thats how you can send data from browser to server (PHP)

Answer (score 0):

You can send data from forms with ajax (you'll need jquery) and receive this in php with $_POST

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    cache:false,
    url:"###.php", //php 
    data:data,    // multiple data sent using ajax
    success: function (data) {
         //show data receive
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at `AJAX`, I give you a link to a good course to learn it:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code and it works:

```
function showScores() {
    var gameOverHTML = "<br><h1>Haz terminado, puedes proceder a abandonar la applicación.<br> Puedes hacer uso de los botones en la barra de navegación</h1>";
    gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> Tu Resultado: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
    var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
    element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addanswer.php",
            datatype: "text",
            data: "TotalScore=" + quiz.score,
            success: function(guardar){
                console.log ("Datos guardados correctamente");
            }            
        }
    )
};
```